# Zip file generating randomly of the size around 100gb on linux server

Tags: java, spring

I have a code where I am supposed to create a zip file and attach it to mail and then mail to particular user. but every day once, a random zip file is getting generated of the size 50gb or 100 or 200 GB on Linux server.i have applied loggers and I am checking the file size before mailing so before mailing the size is what it is supposed to be in MBS or KBS.i am not able to find the root cause and not able to diagnose the issue. given below is my code

```
public void sendPlainTextEmail(String struseremailId, String strtoAddress,
        String strsubject, String body, final String genetaredId) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    ClassLoader classLoader =
               Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(classLoader.getResource("resources/log4j.properties"));
    logger.info("inside sendPlainTextEmail");
    Properties ldapProperties = new Properties();
    try
    {
    InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/ldap.properties");
    
    ldapProperties.load(inputStream);
    
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    struseremailId = ldapProperties.getProperty("emailid");
    System.out.println("String To Address "+strtoAddress +" "+genetaredId);
    // sets SMTP server properties
    

    
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", emailHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);

    final String authUserEmail = this.authUserEmail;
    final String authUserPswd = this.authUserPswd;
    
    
    
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("id",genetaredId);
    parameters.put(DOC_TYPE, "FAF");
    parameters.put(REPORT_TYPE, "PDF Report");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    String fileName=genetaredId.replace("/", "-");
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/reports/formWiseReport_FAF.jrxml");
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
        
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters,dataSource.getConnection());
        } catch (JRException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
     }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);
    } catch (JRException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   
    DataSource ds =  new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
    DataHandler pdfdh = new DataHandler(ds); 
    
    Session session = null;
    try {
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {return new PasswordAuthentication(authUserEmail, authUserPswd);}};
        session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(struseremailId));
        //String[] toAddress ="suresh.molleti@spriertech.com,".split(",");
       // String[] toAddress ="parusharam.kunnur@spriertech.com,suresh.molleti@spriertech.com,basit.meraz@spriertech.com".split(",");
        String[] toAddress = strtoAddress.split(",");
        
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String s : toAddress) {
           if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
              list.add(s);
           }
        }

        toAddress = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length];
        for(int i=0; i<toAddresses.length; i++) toAddresses[i]= new InternetAddress(toAddress[i]);
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(strsubject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        // set plain text message
      

        // set Html message
        msg.setContent(body+"<br/><br/><a href='http://pamstest.in.panasonic.com/pam/'>PAMS Green Url</a>.", "text/html");
        
        // sends the e-mail
        //msg.setContent(body+"<br/><br/><a href='"+AnchorGreenController.applicationUrl+"/'>Anchor Green Url</a>.", "text/html");
        msg.setContent(body, "text/html");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        
        List<Documents> beans = null;
        String name = null;
        String zipFile = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId+"/"+fileName+".zip";
        String dirPath = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId;
        System.out.println(dirPath);
        System.out.println(zipFile);

        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
         
        try {
            
            // create byte buffer
           
 
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
 
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                System.out.println("Adding file: " + files[i].getName());
 
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
 
                // begin writing a new ZIP entry, positions the stream to the start of the entry data
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
                 
                int length;
 
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
 
                zos.closeEntry();
 
                // close the InputStream
                fis.close();
                buffer=null;
            }
 
            // close the ZipOutputStream
            
            zos.close();
            
            File file = new File(zipFile);
            double sizeMb=(double)file.length() / (1024 * 1024);
            double sizeKb=(double) file.length() / 1024 ;
            logger.info("Zip File Size in mb "+sizeMb);
            System.out.println("Zip File Size in mb "+sizeMb);
            logger.info("Zip File Size in kb "+sizeKb);
            System.out.println("Zip File Size in kb "+sizeKb);
            if(sizeMb>10) {
                //SendAlertAttachment(genetaredId);
                File zipFileDelete = new File(zipFile);
                boolean deleted = zipFileDelete.delete();
                logger.info("Zip File Deleted Which was exceeding 10MB for id:::::"+genetaredId);
                //generateZipAgain(genetaredId,fileName);
            }
             
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error creating zip file" + ioe.getStackTrace().toString());
            logger.error("error creating zip file", ioe);
        }
        
        String dirPath1 = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId;
        File dir1 = new File(dirPath1);
        
        File[] files1 = dir1.listFiles();
        String zipname="";
        FinancialApproval fa= piService.getFAFData(genetaredId);
        
         if (files1 != null) {
            if (files1.length == 0) {
            } else {
                beans = new ArrayList<Documents>();
                Documents bean = null;
                for (File aFile : files1) {
                    bean = new Documents();
                    bean.setReqId(genetaredId);
                    bean.setFilename(aFile.getName());
                    name = aFile.getName();
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(fileName+".zip")) {
                        
                        zipname = aFile.getName();
                        }
                        beans.add(bean);
                }
            }
        }
         DataSource source=null;
         DataHandler dh = null;
         String fullpathnam="";
        if(zipname!=null && !zipname.isEmpty()) {
         fullpathnam = dirPath+"/"+zipname;
        System.out.println(fullpathnam);
        
         source = new FileDataSource(fullpathnam);
         dh = new DataHandler(source);
        }
        
       /* String filename = "C:/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/"+ genetaredId;
       File n = new File(filename);
        
       File[] listOfFiles = n.listFiles();

       for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
         if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            filename =   "C:/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/"+listOfFiles[i].getName();
             DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
             messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
             messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // Send the complete message parts
             msg.setContent(multipart);
            
           System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
           System.out.println("/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
         } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
             System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
         }
       }*/
       
       MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       textBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
       
       
       
       MimeBodyPart AttachBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
       AttachBodyPart1.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
       AttachBodyPart1.setDataHandler(pdfdh);
       String title=fa.getTitle();
       if(title.length()>35){
           title=title.substring(0,35);
       }
       System.out.println("filename::"+fileName+","+title+".pdf");
     
       AttachBodyPart1.setFileName(fileName+","+title+".pdf");
       logger.info(fileName+".pdf");
       System.out.println();
       
       File file1 = new File(fullpathnam);
       if(zipname!=null && !zipname.isEmpty()) {
        logger.info("Inside Attaching zip file part");
       MimeBodyPart AttachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       AttachBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
       AttachBodyPart.setDataHandler(dh);
       if(zipname.contains(".zip")){
           zipname= zipname.replace(".zip", "");
           System.out.println(zipname);
           zipname=zipname+","+title+".zip";
       }
       logger.info("zipfile::"+zipname);
       AttachBodyPart.setFileName(zipname);
       logger.info("Attachment Name set");
       multipart.addBodyPart(AttachBodyPart);
       logger.info("Attachmening zip file to mail");
      
       double sizeMbs=(double)file1.length() / (1024 * 1024);
       double sizeKbs=(double) file1.length() / 1024 ;
       logger.info("Zip File Size in mb while attaching "+sizeMbs);
       logger.info("Zip File Size in kb while attaching "+sizeKbs);
    
       }
       
      
       multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
       
       multipart.addBodyPart(AttachBodyPart1);
       msg.setContent(multipart);
       double sizeMbsBeforeMail=(double)file1.length() / (1024 * 1024);
       logger.info("Zip Size Before Mailing:::"+sizeMbsBeforeMail);
        Transport.send(msg);
        logger.info("email send");
        logger.info("Zip path after mail send::"+fullpathnam);
        File file = new File(fullpathnam);
        double sizeMb1=(double)file.length() / (1024 * 1024);
        double sizeKb1=(double) file.length() / 1024 ;
        logger.info("Zip File Size in mb after mailing "+sizeMb1);
        System.out.println("Zip File Size in mb after mailing "+sizeMb1);
        logger.info("Zip File Size in kb after mailing"+sizeKb1);
        System.out.println("Zip File Size in kb after mailing"+sizeKb1);
        boolean deleteZipAfterMail=file.delete();
        if(deleteZipAfterMail==false || sizeMb1>10) {
            file.delete();
            logger.info("delted 2nd time after mail send");
        }
    } catch (AddressException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("AddressException::"+ae.getStackTrace());
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("MessagingException::"+me.getStackTrace());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception::"+e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you highlights the important parts of your code? Your code way too long, with a lot of noise which makes it extremly difficult to understand, potentially reproduce the error and therefore help you.

Comment: post the ouput of System.out.println("Adding file: " + files[i].getName()); and add the size of the file to it.

Comment: What is in the large mails?

Comment: Also do any exceptions happen? Your error handling is non-existent.

Comment: What is in these huge zip archives? Inspecting them could help find how they get generated. For example, do they contain files they shouldn't have

Comment: How does `genetaredId` get generated? Is it possible the same id is used more than once?

Comment: so basically that my production code so i need to delete that zip file fast and cannot copy that zip file to my local from linux server as it is of the size 100gb

Comment: so for each request new id is getting generated,there is a separate method for generated id

Comment: there is no exceptions when large files get genarated it just doen't get attached to email

Comment: so once zip is generated i am checking its file size and while attaching to email i am again checking the file size so before Transport.send the size is fine.so if large file is generated the mail dosen't gets send and if there is no lrge file it executes normally

Comment: so my question is it happening because i haven't close fileoutputstream??

Answer (score 0):

The zip file you are creating is inside the directory that you're putting into the zip file.

```
    String zipFile = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId+"/"+fileName+".zip";
    String dirPath = "/data/PamGreenSource/Documents/" + genetaredId;
```

This means that if `genetaredId` is reused, the code will try to add the (incomplete) zip file into itself as an entry. Since the zip file keeps growing as you write to it, it may take some time for the reader to get to the end of the file.

Solutions:

You could put the zip file somewhere else. Or you could delete the existing zip file before you list the directory contents. Or you could check if the file you are adding to the zip archive is not the zip acrhive itself:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
             byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            if (files[i].getName().equals(fileName+".zip")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Adding file: " + files[i].getName());
```

Comment: there is no existing zip file

Comment: so my question is it happening because i haven't close fileoutputstream??

Comment: How do you know there is no existing zip file -  you don't have code to make sure? "In theory" the file output stream is closed when you call `zos.close()` - but that method will not be called if an exception occurs and possibly some other scenarios.

Comment: so my question is if zip file is getting reused why doesn't it happens to all the request,in my case it is happening to 1 or 2 cases a day

Comment: When zip file is created i am checking the file size 2 or 3 times where it dint showed me anything.the file size was around in mbs

Comment: It is possible this occurs only as a side effect of another error having happened. You have no `finally` clauses that are guaranteed to run when an error occurs, so It's difficult say for certain what will happen or which of your debug logs will be skipped. Trying to attach a multi GB file into an email will very likely result in an "out of memory error". Refactor your code so it uses smaller methods and improve the error handling. Use the finally clause and/or try-with-resources to make sure that files you open are closed and that things you want to log are guaranteed to be logged.

Comment: now i have closed connections in try catch and in finally block as well and i have used your code of checking existing zip.

Comment: closing connections in try catch and finally block won't harm my code right?